# Docker compose request between containers could not resolve host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have two separate docker containers, each running an api (auth_api and user_api).
I am trying to make a get request from the `user_api` service to the `auth_api` service but it fails with this error: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: auth_api`

These are my docker-compose files:
`/auth`

```
version: '3'
services:
  auth_api:
    build:
      context: .
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"

networks:
  default:
    name: shopnet
    external: false
```

`/user`

```
version: '3'
services:
  user_api:
    build:
      context: .
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001
    ports: 
      - "8001:8001"

networks:
  shopnet:
    external: true
```

The `shopnet` network is created because it shows up in the list: `docker network ls`

I am executing the GET request with curl directly from the `user_api` container:
`curl http://auth_api:8000/auth`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `user_api` service doesn't have a `networks:` block, so it connects to the `default` network that Compose automatically provides.  You declare a separate `shopnet` network, but don't attach your network to it.  ([Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71569255) addresses this by explicitly naming the other network.)

You can [configure the `default` network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network) to make the "user" `default` network be the same as the "auth" `default` network:

```yaml
# user/docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  user_api:
    build: .
    ports: ['8081:8081']
    # networks: [default] # automatically provided by Compose

networks:
  default:
    name: shopnet
    external: true
```

You also may be able to put both services in the same `docker-compose.yml` file, depending on your specific setup, and then you wouldn't need any manual `networks:` setup at all.

Answer (score 0):

Docker doesn't use `_` in the hostname anymore.

Unless you didn't update for ages, replace `_` by `-`.

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/229

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adding

```
networks:
  - default
  - shopnet
```

to the user_api service fixes the problem